# implement Neural Network in python

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to implement Neural Network(NN) in python with numpy, and I found that my NN doesn't work as expected.

I have checked the numerical gradient and compare it with gradient calculated by Back Propagation. It turns out that I'm right. But the cost decreases very slowly and it rebounds after some epochs.

I'm trying to solve the problem of Exclusive Or. But my NN seems ignore the input vector of each sample and tend to predict all the samples to the percentage of samples which label is 1(E.g if I feed it with 3 positive samples and 1 negative sample ,it will predict all the four samples to about 0.75).

Can anyone help me with this problem? This has already perplexed me for a long time.

Here is the structure of neural network and some formula

[structure of NN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltI4J.png)

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C88X.png)

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(565113221)

def sigmoid(x): # sigmoid function 
    return 1/(1+np.power(np.e,-x))

def forward(x,W1,W2,b1,b2): # feed forward
    a = W1.dot(x)
    z = sigmoid(a+b1)
    b = W2.dot(z)
    y = sigmoid(b+b2)
    return a,z,b,y

def pred(X,W1,W2,b1,b2): # predict
    y_pred = np.zeros((X.shape[0],1))
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        _,_,_,y_pred[i] = forward(x.reshape((-1,1)),W1,W2,b1,b2)
    return y_pred

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]) # features 4 * 2
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]]) # labels 4 * 1

epsilon = 0.12 # initialize all weighs between -0.12 ~ 0.12
W1 = np.random.random((2,2)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon # map from input to hidden
b1 = np.random.random((2,1)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon # bias1 
W2 = np.random.random((1,2)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon # map from hidden to output
b2 = np.random.random((1,1)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon # bias2
epoch = 50 # maximum training turns
alpha = 0.01 # learning rate
for turn in range(epoch):
    print('turn:',turn,end=' ')
    epoch_cost = 0
    for index in range(X.shape[0]):
        x = X[index,:].reshape((-1,1))
        y = Y[index,:].reshape((-1,1))
        a,z,b,y_pred = forward(x,W1,W2,b1,b2) # feed forward

        cost = -y.dot(np.log(y_pred)) - (1-y).dot(np.log(1-y_pred)) # calculate cost
        epoch_cost += cost # calculate cumulative cost of this epoch

        for k in range(W2.shape[0]): # update W2
            for j in range(W2.shape[1]):
                W2[k,j] -= alpha * (y_pred - y) * z[j,0]

        for k in range(b2.shape[0]): # update b2
            b2[k,0] -= alpha * (y_pred - y)


        for j in range(W1.shape[0]): # update W1
            for i in range(W1.shape[1]):
                for k in range(W2.shape[0]):
                    W1[j,i] -= alpha * (y_pred - y) * W2[k,j] * z[j,0] * (1 - z[j,0]) * x[i]

        for j in range(b1.shape[0]): # update b1
            b1[j,0] -= alpha * (y_pred - y) * W2[k,j] * z[j,0] * (1 - z[j,0])

    print('cost:',epoch_cost)


print('prediction\n',pred(X,W1,W2,b1,b2))
print('ground-truth\n',Y)
```

Comment: Your gradient updates to W1 and b1 should use the original values of W2, not the new ones.

Comment: bug in pred(): it should initialize `x` in the inner loop

Comment: Thanks, I should update the parameters simultaneously, and there is a bug in pred()

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer. I have just replaced gradient descent with something similar to a simple [evolution strategy (ES)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08842). This works, so there probably is no bug in your forward pass.

```
# [...] sigmoid(), forward(), pred() not modified

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]) # features 4 * 2
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]]) # labels 4 * 1

W1 = np.zeros((2,2)) # map from input to hidden
b1 = np.zeros((2,1)) # bias1 
W2 = np.zeros((1,2)) # map from hidden to output
b2 = np.zeros((1,1)) # bias2
epoch = 2000 # maximum training turns
for turn in range(epoch):
    print('turn:',turn,end=' ')
    epoch_cost = 0
    for index in range(X.shape[0]):
        x = X[index,:].reshape((-1,1))
        y = Y[index,:].reshape((-1,1))
        a,z,b,y_pred = forward(x,W1,W2,b1,b2) # feed forward

        cost = -y.dot(np.log(y_pred)) - (1-y).dot(np.log(1-y_pred)) # calculate cost
        epoch_cost += cost # calculate cumulative cost of this epoch

    if turn == 0 or epoch_cost < epoch_cost_best:
        epoch_cost_best = epoch_cost
        W1_best = W1
        b1_best = b1
        W2_best = W2
        b2_best = b2

    epsilon = 0.12 # perturb all weighs between -0.12 ~ 0.12
    W1 = W1_best + np.random.random((2,2)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon
    b1 = b1_best + np.random.random((2,1)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon
    W2 = W2_best + np.random.random((1,2)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon
    b2 = b2_best + np.random.random((1,1)) * epsilon * 2 - epsilon

    print('cost:',epoch_cost)


print('prediction\n',pred(X,W1_best,W2_best,b1_best,b2_best))
print('ground-truth\n',Y)
```

Comment: Amazing! I never see this strategy before.Thank you for that. But there is a bug in pred() because I did not initialize x.